# Swift 4: errors encountered while discovering extensions

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm currently building an app that displays firebase users in a tableview. However, I am getting this error in my debugger:

> Code=13 "query cancelled" 
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Here is my imagePickerController function;

```
@IBAction func selectpicture(_ sender: Any)
{
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
      self.imageview.image = image
        signupBTN.isHidden = false
    }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have already included "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" in my `info.plist` as well as included "`picker.delegate = self`" in my `viewDidLoad()`.

Here is my user info code;

```
let userInfo: [String: Any] = ["uid": user.uid,"fullname": self.fullname, "urlToImage": url.absoluteString]
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)
```

Lastly, this my code to implement the image in the table view cell;

```
cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
```

Because of this, it is causing my app to crash with a 
Thread 1:

> "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help!

Comment: This may not help, but iOS 11 added a *new* privacy key - "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" or `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`. (This caused me grief a few months ago.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems not have made any difference. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What type has the `user` member var and where does it get its contents from? The error message tells us that you unwrapped a nil value, and the only part of the shown code that can directly cause this is in `self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!` -- apparently `imagePath` is not set on the user at indexPath.row.

Comment: I created a NSobject file for user (class User: NSObject), and it consists of 
  "var imagePath: String!"